# WCF, Xamarin - CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert to System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wcf, observablecollection

Having a convertion issue between my WCF service returned ObservableCollection and handling the result to fill a ListView.

So in both WCF and PCL Projects i have this Temoignage.cs in Model folder

```
    public class Temoignage
    {
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public string Prenom { get; set; }
        public int Note { get; set; }
        public string Texte { get; set; }
    }
```

The WCF service returning this

```
public ObservableCollection<Temoignage> GetTemoignage()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Temoignage> TemoignageList = new ObservableCollection<Temoignage>();

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select U.nom, U.Prenom, T.note, T.texte from dbo.Temoignages T inner join Users U on U.id = T.iduser where T.validation = 1;", con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Temoignage temoignage = new Temoignage
                    {
                        Nom = reader.GetString(0),
                        Prenom = reader.GetString(1),
                        Note = reader.GetInt32(2),
                        Texte = reader.GetString(3)
                    };
                    TemoignageList.Add(temoignage);
                }

            return TemoignageList;
        }
```

And the ViewModel which receive it

```
    public ObservableCollection<Temoignage> TemoignagesList { get; set; }
....
public void Temoignages()
        {

            BasicHttpBinding binding = CreateBasicHttp();
            this.client1 = new BienEtreServiceClient(binding, EndPoint);
            this.instance = ((IBienEtreService)client1.InnerChannel);

            client1.GetTemoignageCompleted += ClientOnGetTemoignageCompleted;

            client1.GetTemoignageAsync();
        }



        public void ClientOnGetTemoignageCompleted(object sender, GetTemoignageCompletedEventArgs e)
        {   // The problems starts here
            ObservableCollection<Temoignage> TemTest = e.Result;

            foreach (Temoignage item in TemTest)
            {
                TemoignagesList.Add(item);
            }

        }
```

I thought i could, in ClientOnGetTemoignageCompleted, just take the ObservableCollection i got from WCF and add the elements in my already existing TemoignagesList (which is binded to XAML).
But nope. Even if the Models contains same elements in both projects.

e.Result containt elements i need, i just don't know how to read them.
[equals to this when ClientOnGetTemoignageCompleted is executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFRfV.png)

Am i missing an important point?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I think i found it myself, using the models of my wcf service and not the client ones

```
//using BienEtre.Models;
using BienEtreWcfService;
```

Now this works and add elements to the list.

```
public void ClientOnGetTemoignageCompleted(object sender, GetTemoignageCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (Temoignage item in e.Result)
            {
                TemoignagesList.Add(item);
            }

        }
```

Not sure i understood, but it works!

I'm also using List instead of ObservableCollection.